# How to turn all rand_mode on effectively after partially turn them off in systermverilog

Tags: random, constraints, system-verilog

I have classes as below:

```
class h1_c;
  rand bit[1:0] h1_a;
  rand bit[1:0] h1_b;
  h2_c h2;
  function new()
    h2 = new();
  endfunction
endclass

class h2_c;
  rand bit[1:0] h2_a;
  rand bit[1:0] h2_b;
  h3_c h3;
  function new()
    h3 = new();
  endfunction
endclass

class h3_c;
  rand bit[1:0] h3_a;
  rand bit[1:0] h3_b;
endclass

module p1;   
  h1_c h1;

  initial begin
    h1 = new();
    h1.h2.h2_a.rand_mode(0);
    h1.h2.h3.h3_a.rand_mode(0);
    h1.randomize();
    //How to turn all rand_mode on effectively after I turn them off seperately.
    //which like h1.*.rand_mode(1);
  end
endmodule
```

I turn some variables' `rand` mode off and want to turn them all on effectively after `randomize()`. Is there any efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the variable name when using rand_mode(1) to set all variables in the object, according to section 18.8 of the 1800-2017 LRM

i.e.

```
h1.rand_mode(1);
// is equivalent to 
h1.h1_a.rand_mode(1);
h1.h1_b.rand_mode(1);
h1.h1_c.rand_mode(1);
```

And that should recursively descend into h1.h1_c setting its rand_mode variables. But I would check your tool as this behavior is not obvious from reading the LRM.